# Trigger 'Is Active' switched off as soon as I start editing, why?

Tags: apex, trigger

For the sandboxes of one particular org, I notice that as soon as I start editing an active trigger, via the standard editor in the browser, the trigger is marked as inactive in the editor. I have to manually click the check box to make it active again. Fortunately, the version of the trigger that is live is still active. However, should I forget to manually click the check box, before clicking Save, the trigger is indeed made inactive. This has caused some headaches before I found out what was going on.

I have noticed this behavior only for the sandboxes for this particular org, for other orgs it doesn't do this. The behavior is consistent: it's happening for each active trigger that I start editing. Googling hasn't brought up anything. Anyone who has seen this before and knows how to prevent this annoying behavior?

Comment: what is the edition you are using?

Comment: Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is standard behavior. Even today, more than 4 years after asking this question, I still cannot find documentation about this behavior. But it still happens: as soon as you get into the editor to changing the code, the trigger is switched to inactive.

It's anyone's guess as to why this is happening. My first thought: maybe to prevent potentially erroneous triggers to run right after save. But it is not possible to test a trigger when it is inactive. And edits on normal Apex classes are live as soon as you save them. Strange.